# Output of a function line by line not as a list python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a function and its output is returned as a list,

[32,1,4,5,6]

But I want it to return in this manner,
*32

1

4

5

6*

How do I return the output as above?

Comment: loop and print the values

Comment: Have you done any research to figure this out on your own?

Comment: Returning a list seems to be the correct thing to do here. The caller can then loop over that list and print each item on a separate line if that's what you want.

Comment: This is for an exam and it requires the the output to be in that format. So I was just wondering. Maybe that's how they want it. Or is there a way to return the output from the function in that manner?

Comment: Let’s just state the obvious here.  If this is for an exam, and you’re asking us to do the work for you, isn’t that cheating / unethical? Perhaps if you *researched* the solution to various steps might be a more ethical approach.  And too, in your potential career as a programmer, you’re going to have to learn problem solving on your own. We can help with specific details, but you’re going to have to learn to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the list and get the result, as:

```
result = list(range(10)) # your lists values
for i in result:
    print(i)
```

or you can use:

```
print(*result, sep='\n')
```

using functions

```
>>> def func(n):
...     for i in range(n):
...             yield i
... 
>>> for i in func(10):
...     print(i)
... 
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
>>> def func2(n):
...     result = []
...     for i in range(n):
...             result.append(i)
...     return '\n'.join(str(i) for i in result)
... 
>>> func2(10)
'0\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9'
>>> x = func2(10)
>>> print(x)
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: This is for an exam and it requires the the output to be in that format. So I was just wondering. Maybe that's how they want it. Or is there a way to return the output from the function in that manner?

Comment: updated using function

Answer (score 0):

```py
my_list = the_function_that_returns_a_list()

for item in my_list:
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add the following code for getting required output

```
string = ""

for i in result :
    string += i +"/n"
```